# Polymer accessing child Shadow DOM elements from parent Shadow DOM and Parent Shadow DOM elements from child Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

**parent component**

```
 <link rel="import" href="../elements/multi-child.html">
    <dom-module  id="multi-dom">
        <template>
            <h1 id="element-in-parent-dom">Element in parent DOM</h1>
            <multi-child></multi-child>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
              is: "multi-dom",
            ready:function(){
              var elementinchilddom = document.getElementById('element-in-child-dom');
              if(elementinchilddom){
                console.log('Parent Dom able to find Element in child dom');
              }
              else{
                console.log('Parent Dom unable to find Element in child dom');
              }
            }
            });
        </script>
     </<dom-module>
```

**child component**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module  id="multi-child">
    <template>
        <h1 id="element-in-child-dom">Element in child DOM</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
          is: "multi-child",
        ready:function(){
          var elementinparentdom = document.getElementById('element-in-parent-dom');
          if(elementinparentdom){
            console.log('Child Dom able to find element-in-parent-dom');
          }
          else{
            console.log('Child dom unable to find element-in-parent-dom');
          }
        }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module >
```

I have created a demo parent component and child component.When I include the tag `<multi-dom></multi-dom>` .I am getting the following result

> Hello World unable to find element-in-parent-dom
>
> Hello World unable to find Element in child dom

Is there any other ways to access the child and parent DOM elements?
Also is it possible to access shadow DOM elements using document object(This is required for automation)

Comment: What you try is actually not a good idea, because it will tie your elements together on implementation details. Why do you want to access DOM this way?

Comment: I wanted to make a custom container element which will act like an I frame container  so that I can load third party addins into it safely .I need complete shielding from CSS styles as well as JavaScripts.But the parent elements should still be able to access its children .

Comment: You should rethink your strategy IMO. I've tried, and not even `Polymer.dom().querySelector()` lets you directly select children from inside of other element.

Comment: And regarding shielding, you won't get 100% CSS shielding even with Shadow DOM. Even worse for you, the spec doesn't offer any JS shielding at all.